# Are there legitimate saints not documented in western hagiology?

Tags: catholicism, hagiography

In Croatia the patron saint of Vukovar is Saint Bonus/Sveti Bono. There's nothing in any English Catholic encyclopedia but Croatian wikipedia lists the following facts:

- Martyred under Decian (or was it Valens?) in the third century
- There's an inscription of his name on a street in Rome.
- His body was donated to the people in Vinkovski by Benedict XIV

How common is it for saints of one region to be "left out" in the English hagiographies?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [*Roman Martyrology* for August 1](https://isidore.co/divinum/cgi-bin/horas/officium.pl?command=prayPrima&date=07-31-2018&browsertime=11-23-2018&searchvalue=11) says:

> Likewise at Rome, upon the Latin Way, [in the third century,] the holy martyrs **Bonus the Priest**, Faustus, and Maurus, and nine others, of whom it is written in the Acts of holy [Pope [St.] Stephen [I]](https://www.bartleby.com/210/8/021.html).
>
> <sup>Romæ, via Latína, sanctórum Mártyrum Boni Presbýteri, Fausti et Mauri, cum áliis novem; qui in Actis sancti Stéphani Papæ describúntur.</sup>

cf. also [p. 228 of this *Roman Martyrology*](https://archive.org/details/romanmartyrology00cathuoft/page/228)

[Pope St. Stephen I](https://www.bartleby.com/210/8/021.html) reigned from 253-257, during which time Valerian was emperor.

Comment: Thank you for providing an English source!

Comment: Is "the Acts of holy Pope [St.] Stephen" extant?

Comment: @TomislavOstojich I don't think so. [Migne collected some of his writings](http://www.documentacatholicaomnia.eu/01_01_0254-0257-_Stephanus_I,_Sanctus.html), though. Original source: Migne's [_Patrologiæ Latina_ pp. 1015](https://archive.org/details/patrologiaecur03mign/page/n557)ff.

Answer (score 2):

Are there legitimate saints not documented (named) in western hagiology?

The short answer is: **yes**.

As in many situations, the Church assigns to them the date of November 1st as their feast day: [Solemnity of All Saints](https://www.catholicculture.org/culture/liturgicalyear/calendar/day.cfm?date=2015-11-01).

> Today the Church celebrates all the saints: canonized or beatified, **and the multitude of those who are in heaven enjoying the beatific vision that are only known to God**. During the early centuries the Saints venerated by the Church were all martyrs. Later on the Popes set November 1 as the day for commemorating all the Saints. We all have this "universal call to holiness." What must we to do in order to join the company of the saints in heaven? We "must follow in His footsteps and conform [our]selves to His image seeking the will of the Father in all things. [We] must devote [our]selves with all [our] being to the glory of God and the service of [our] neighbor. In this way, the holiness of the People of God will grow into an abundant harvest of good, as is admirably shown by the life of so many saints in Church history" (Lumen Gentium, 40).

The names of many holy martyrs are unknown to God alone. In cases where the names of the martyrs are not known, there is simply an entry for the group. For example:

- [20,000 Martyrs of Nicomedia](http://catholicsaints.info/20000-martyrs-of-nicomedia/)
- [Martyrs of Alexandria](https://www.catholic.org/saints/saint.php?saint_id=4749) Groups of martyrs put to death in the city Alexandria, Egypt. The majority of these martyrs are not named individually but perished in groups.